# Updated site now URL is not working

Tags: redirection

I updated my site and now the site only shows up in Firefox.  I believe it has something to do with the redirect since if I type in mysite.com/mysite then it shows up.  I've tried updating the .htaccess file and the default/settings.php files and can't get it to work correctly.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if there is an error message in the network console of the browser? For example, in Chrome/MSIE, F12 will open a debug console, where there should be a "network" tab. This should provide a more precise error, such as "error 500" or any redirections happening. If you run Linux, you can type "wget -O /dev/null -S http://example.org/mysite".

Answer (score 1):

Check that the following rule is not commented out in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /
```

If you have installed Drupal in a folder inside your root it should be:

```
RewriteBase /my_folder
```

Comment: I had changed the .htaccess file and the settings.php and it didn't work.  I changed them back and then changed the .htaccess file again.  I'm still getting my "missing.html" file served up in the browser for "example.com".  I know it's got to be a simple change somewhere.  FF is working correctly - I enter "example.com" and it redirects to "https: // example.com/ example.  Is there something else that needs to be changed?  Thanks for your help - this is my only site and the only thing I do with it is update it.  This is the first time this has happened - so I'm having to relearn everything.

Comment: If it's working in Firefox it must have something to do with the browser in that case.

Comment: Did you clear the cache in the other browser? Did you make a recent change to the DNS of the site?